# Print 1 to N numbers without using while/If loop

Tags: output

```
    *>printing 1 to a numbers without using if and while ,but this is not working in java
    **class printOut{//class started here
    static int PrintN(int x)
    {
    (x>1)?(System.out.println(PrintN(x--))):System.out.println(x);
//above code is recursively calling PrintN to print decreemented value
    return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    int a=10;//initialized variable
    PrintN(a);//calling the static method wihout creating its object
    }
    }***
```

//my question was to write a program to find out 1 to n numbers without using while or if loops.

Comment: How about [`for loop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to print, starting at 1, until reaching some initial input number, your logic should be to first make the recursive call, then print afterwards, on the way back.  Something like this:

```
public static void printN(int x) {
    if (x > 1) {
        printN(x - 1);
    }

    System.out.println(x);
}
```

I don't think your recursive method has to return any value, because the number/state to be printed is passed along the method calls.  Note also that the base case occurs when the number becomes 1.  In this case, we don't make another recursive call, but rather just print ourself and then return to the higher caller.

### Demo